# difference between static and non static recursive member

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, static

The C++ programming language book mentions like below:

*It is not possible to declare new objects of a struct until its complete declaration has been seen. For example*:

```
struct No_good {
    No_good member; // error : recursive definition
};
```

*This is an error because the compiler is not able to determine the size of No_good*.

But below piece of code is compiling for me.

```
struct No_good {
    static No_good member; // OK: compiling
};
```

how `static` keyword allowing compiler to know the size of `member`. AFAIK static decides the storage class of a named variable.

Comment: Think of the size required if every instance of `No_good` also has a `No_good` member. Hint: You would never have enough. You could get away with a pointer.

Comment: You can try this yourself. Give `No_good` a few static data members of various types and observe the effect on `sizeof(No_good)` -- you will see that there is none.

Comment: Books teaching a new subject are full of [lies we tell to children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children) in the technical sense.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't have a full `No_good` member inside the `No_good` class, as pointed out by Francois Moisan is because it would be infinitely recursive and take infinite space.

A `No_good*` member would be ok because it has a finite space(size of a pointer) and can be null stopping the recursion.

A static member is also ok becuase it is not stored in every instance of `No_good` but instead shared by all of the instances. It is not technically part of the object but something associated with the namespace of `No_good`.

Hope this clears it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can think the static variable as a global variable. Only difference is it is under the class's namespace. So if it was a global variable you could reach it like No_good but if it is static you have to type No_good::No_good. You can do that even you never instantiate the class.

The same troubles you can get into with globals you will get with statics as well. You never know which static variable initializes first if they depend on each other you are still in trouble.

The way I experience it, lots of statics usage comes from writing C++ code with C point of view.